PowerBi - cannot get data correct into my table
I am trying to get data regarding demografic in Denmark but I struggle to get Data right.
I want to have each quarter for the year 2020 on 4 rows wiht each quarter and the number of people each quarter but the quarter are in each column and when I try to remove pivot I get 16 rows and that is also wrong.
Please find attache picture with the problem.
Can you please help?

The code is:
let

Kilde = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FOLK1A/JSONSTAT?Tid=2020K1&Tid=2020K2&Tid=2020K3&Tid=2020K4")),

#"Konverteret til tabel" = Record.ToTable(Kilde),

#"Se Kilde" = Table.FirstN(#"Konverteret til tabel", 1),

#"Udvidet Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Konverteret til tabel", "Value", {"dimension", "label", "source", "updated", "value"}, {"Value.dimension", "Value.label", "Value.source", "Value.updated", "Value.value"}),

#"Udvidet Value.dimension" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Value", "Value.dimension", {"Tid"}, {"Value.dimension.Tid"}),

#"Udvidet Value.dimension.Tid" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Value.dimension", "Value.dimension.Tid", {"label", "category"}, {"Kvartal", "Kategori"}),

#"Udvidet Kategori" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Value.dimension.Tid", "Kategori", {"label"}, {"Kategori.label"}),

#"Udvidet Kategori.label1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Kategori", "Kategori.label", {"2020K1", "2020K2", "2020K3", "2020K4"}, {"Kategori.label.2020K1", "Kategori.label.2020K2", "Kategori.label.2020K3", "Kategori.label.2020K4"}),

#"Udvidet Value.value1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Udvidet Kategori.label1", "Value.value"),

#"Fjernede andre kolonner" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Udvidet Value.value1",{"Kategori.label.2020K1", "Kategori.label.2020K2", "Kategori.label.2020K3", "Kategori.label.2020K4", "Value.source", "Value.value"})

in

#"Fjernede andre kolonner"


Do you need something like that?

Would be:
let Kilde = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FOLK1A JSONSTAT?Tid=2020K1&Tid=2020K2&Tid=2020K3&Tid=2020K4")),#"Konverteret til tabel" = Record.ToTable(Kilde),#"Se Kilde" = Table.FirstN(#"Konverteret til tabel", 1),#"Udvidet Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Konverteret til tabel", "Value", {"dimension", "label", "source", "updated", "value"}, {"Value.dimension", "Value.label", "Value.source", "Value.updated", "Value.value"}),#"Udvidet Value.dimension" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Value", "Value.dimension", {"Tid"}, {"Value.dimension.Tid"}),#"Udvidet Value.dimension.Tid" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Value.dimension", "Value.dimension.Tid", {"label", "category"}, {"Kvartal", "Kategori"}),#"Udvidet Kategori" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Value.dimension.Tid", "Kategori", {"label"}, {"Kategori.label"}),#"Udvidet Kategori.label1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Udvidet Kategori", "Kategori.label", {"2020K1", "2020K2", "2020K3", "2020K4"}, {"Kategori.label.2020K1", "Kategori.label.2020K2", "Kategori.label.2020K3", "Kategori.label.2020K4"}),#"Udvidet Value.value1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Udvidet Kategori.label1", "Value.value"),#"Fjernede andre kolonner" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Udvidet Value.value1",{"Kategori.label.2020K1", "Kategori.label.2020K2", "Kategori.label.2020K3", "Kategori.label.2020K4", "Value.source", "Value.value"}),
#"Columnas quitadas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Fjernede andre kolonner",{"Value.source"}),
#"Se ha anulado la dinamización de las columnas seleccionadas únicamente." = Table.Unpivot(#"Columnas quitadas", {"Kategori.label.2020K1", "Kategori.label.2020K2", "Kategori.label.2020K3", "Kategori.label.2020K4"}, "Atributo", "Valor"),
#"Columnas reordenadas" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Se ha anulado la dinamización de las columnas seleccionadas únicamente.",{"Atributo", "Valor", "Value.value"}),
#"Filas ordenadas" = Table.Sort(#"Columnas reordenadas",{{"Valor", Order.Ascending}}) in #"Filas ordenadas"

